# How can we prove that some function, .e.g., the hyperbolic tangent function, tends to be linear around zero?

Tags: functions, linear-approximation

I have found this [interesting answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2851702/121164) about increasing the linear range of the hyperbolic tangent function.

Now, I am looking for a proof (or at least have a reference from literature if it shows up to be too convoluted) that the following function becomes near linear for high $\gamma$ values.

$$
    f(x,\gamma)=\frac{2}{\left(1+e^{-2x\gamma^{-1}}\right)}-1
$$

Something that seems to make this harder is that:

$$
\lim\limits_{\gamma \to \inf}f(x,\gamma)=0
$$

Is is possible to demonstrate the linear behavior near zero in a clear way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $x \ll \gamma$, you may consider a (first-order) Taylor expansion of $f$ around $x = 0$ :
$$
\begin{align}
f_\gamma(x) 
   &= \frac{2}{1 + e^{-2x/\gamma}} - 1 \\
   &= \frac{2}{1 + (1 - 2x/\gamma + \mathcal{O}(x^2))} - 1 \\
   &= \frac{1}{1 - x/\gamma + \mathcal{O}(x^2)} - 1 \\
   &= (1 + \frac{x}{\gamma} + \mathcal{O}(x^2)) - 1 \\
   &= \frac{x}{\gamma} + \mathcal{O}(x^2)
\end{align}
$$

Comment: How did $x$ go from denominator to numerator?

Comment: @dawid  With the help of the geometric series, i.e. $$\frac{1}{1-z} = 1 + z  + z^2 + \ldots$$

Answer (score 1):

First I'm going to make a minor change to the proposed function and use the following one:
$$
f_\gamma(x) = \gamma\left(\frac{2}{1 + e^{-2x\gamma^{-1}}} - 1\right)
$$
I added the additional $\gamma$ so that the function converges to the line $y = x$.

Now to prove that $f_\gamma(x)$ converges to the line with increasing $\gamma$. We can simply show that the function converges to the line at every point. Let's choose $x_0$ as a fixed point and show the limiting behavior:
$$
\begin{align}
\lim_{\gamma\to\inf} f_\gamma(x_0) & =
\lim_{\gamma\to\inf} \gamma\left(\frac{2}{1 + e^{-2x_0\gamma^{-1}}} - 1\right) \\
&=\lim_{\gamma\to\inf} \frac{\frac{2}{1 + e^{-2x_0\gamma^{-1}}} - 1}{\gamma^{-1}} \\
&\stackrel{\text{l'H}}{=}\lim_{\gamma\to\inf} \frac{-\frac{2(2x_0\gamma^{-2})e^{-2x_0\gamma^{-1}}}{(1 + e^{-2x_0\gamma^{-1}})^2}}{-\gamma^{-2}} \\
&=\lim_{\gamma\to\inf}\frac{4x_0e^{-2x_0\gamma^{-1}}}{(1 + e^{-2x_0\gamma^{-1}})^2} \\
&=\frac{4x_0}{2^2} \\
&= x_0
\end{align}
$$
Thus $f_\gamma(x) = x$ as $\gamma$ goes to infinity.